# How to use Open Source Android application code

Tags: android, open-source

I want to build a new Android project based on another project that is available open source via Google Code. I already downloaded the code via svn and loaded tested it in Eclipse.
But now when I try to run the code on a phone where the original app is installed I get the "Re-installation failed due to different application signatures" error.

What do I have to change in the app preferences of my branch in order for it to be a new, independent app that is not associated with the source app so that both can be installed alongside?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to uninstall the original version of the open source app.
Once you run it from your local eclipse it will use your debug key which is different than the original key - hence the signature error

Answer (score 1):

Try rooting your phone then uninstalling the system app using adb then installing your custom one